# What the name of the row caret in a DataGridView.CurrentRow

Tags: datagridview

What is the official DataGridView nomenclature description of the little black triangle in the first column?

It seems to mark the position of DataGridView.CurrentRow, but it's a get property only, and I'd like to set it.

[Grid with arrow indicating caret http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3851/gridl.png](http://img180.imageshack.us/img180/3851/gridl.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The "Row Indicator" located in the "Row Header" indicates which row is current.
2. The "Row Header" is also called the "Row Selector".
3. More importantly, to change the current row, you must set the [`CurrentCell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell.aspx) property to a cell in the desired row. From the Remarks section of DataGridView.CurrentRow Property at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentrow.aspx.